# Dart - event.preventDefault is not woking for IE

Tags: events, dart

I am writing a Dart program that has to suppress some browser-specific keys, like Alt-H (shortcut for Help in IE) and do something programmatic instead.

I intercept both keyUp and keyDown events (window.onKeyDown and window.onKeyUp) and, if this is a key+mod (like Alt-H) that matches our custom definition, I call

> e.preventDefault()

and process this event later in the code.

This works in Chrome and FF, but in IE the call to e.preventDefault() does not seem to have any effect. I checked `e.defaultPrevented` value and it is "true". IE shows Help dialog and the event is not propagated any further.

Are there any special tricks for IE? Is this a known bug/feature?

Comment: And there is not more e.returnValue available that was IE specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that IE does not support canceling keyups/downs/presses where the ALT key is invoked. Thats my simple answer here.

You cannot cancel STRG+N in Chrome for example.

Regards,
Robert